# Is there a way to check whether a file exist using webhdfs REST API?

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs

Is there a way to check whether some file with the same name exists on HDFS path via webhdfs REST API?

My Sample URL :

```
http://my-sample-url:port/webhdfs/v15/tmp/mydata/sample.txt?op=CREATE&user.name=john&namenoderpcaddress=prodaddress&createflag=&createparent=true&overwrite=false
```

I'm calling this API through HTTPClient app. How I can check that same name file exist on that hdfs path so that I can decide further processing?

I'm looking for a single line solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can check if the file exists with GETFILESTATUS Rest Call.

`http://[HOST]:[PORT]/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=GETFILESTATUS`

For reference:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#GETFILESTATUS